Unexpected behaviour while swapping strings in C
I am a beginner to programming and today I was trying to swap two strings with somewhat of a raw , brute force logic . But I stumbled upon this behaviour :
My code :
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    char s1[] = "Banned Playbird" ; 
    char s2[] = "Banned Birds" ; 
    void swap(char*,char*) ; 
    swap(s1,s2) ;
    printf("s1 is now: ") ;
    puts(s1) ; 
    printf("s2 is now: ") ;
    puts(s2) ;
    return 0 ; 
}
void swap(char* s1,char* s2)
{
    int i ; 
    int max = (strlen(s1)>strlen(s2)?strlen(s1):strlen(s2)) + 1 ;
    for(i=0;i<max;i++)
    {
        printf("i = %d\n-X-X-X-X-X-X\n",i) ;  
        printf("s1[%d] = %d or %c\ns2[%d] = %d or %c\n",i,s1[i],s1[i],i,s2[i],s2[i]) ;
        char temp = s1[i] ;
        s1[i] = s2[i] ; 
        s2[i] = temp ;
        printf("i = %d\n-X-X-X-X-X-X\n",i) ; 
        printf("s1[%d] = %d or %c\ns2[%d] = %d or %c\n-X-X-X-X-X-X\n\n",i,s1[i],s1[i],i,s2[i],s2[i]) ;
    }
}

Output :
i = 0
-X-X-X-X-X-X
s1[0] = 66 or B
s2[0] = 66 or B
i = 0
-X-X-X-X-X-X
s1[0] = 66 or B
s2[0] = 66 or B
-X-X-X-X-X-X

i = 1
-X-X-X-X-X-X
s1[1] = 97 or a
s2[1] = 97 or a
i = 1
-X-X-X-X-X-X
s1[1] = 97 or a
s2[1] = 97 or a
-X-X-X-X-X-X

i = 2
-X-X-X-X-X-X
s1[2] = 110 or n
s2[2] = 110 or n
i = 2
-X-X-X-X-X-X
s1[2] = 110 or n
s2[2] = 110 or n
-X-X-X-X-X-X

i = 3
-X-X-X-X-X-X
s1[3] = 110 or n
s2[3] = 110 or n
i = 3
-X-X-X-X-X-X
s1[3] = 110 or n
s2[3] = 110 or n
-X-X-X-X-X-X

i = 4
-X-X-X-X-X-X
s1[4] = 101 or e
s2[4] = 101 or e
i = 4
-X-X-X-X-X-X
s1[4] = 101 or e
s2[4] = 101 or e
-X-X-X-X-X-X

i = 5
-X-X-X-X-X-X
s1[5] = 100 or d
s2[5] = 100 or d
i = 5
-X-X-X-X-X-X
s1[5] = 100 or d
s2[5] = 100 or d
-X-X-X-X-X-X

i = 6
-X-X-X-X-X-X
s1[6] = 32 or
s2[6] = 32 or
i = 6
-X-X-X-X-X-X
s1[6] = 32 or
s2[6] = 32 or
-X-X-X-X-X-X

i = 7
-X-X-X-X-X-X
s1[7] = 80 or P
s2[7] = 66 or B
i = 7
-X-X-X-X-X-X
s1[7] = 66 or B
s2[7] = 80 or P
-X-X-X-X-X-X

i = 8
-X-X-X-X-X-X
s1[8] = 108 or l
s2[8] = 105 or i
i = 8
-X-X-X-X-X-X
s1[8] = 105 or i
s2[8] = 108 or l
-X-X-X-X-X-X

i = 9
-X-X-X-X-X-X
s1[9] = 97 or a
s2[9] = 114 or r
i = 9
-X-X-X-X-X-X
s1[9] = 114 or r
s2[9] = 97 or a
-X-X-X-X-X-X

i = 10
-X-X-X-X-X-X
s1[10] = 121 or y
s2[10] = 100 or d
i = 10
-X-X-X-X-X-X
s1[10] = 100 or d
s2[10] = 121 or y
-X-X-X-X-X-X

i = 11
-X-X-X-X-X-X
s1[11] = 98 or b
s2[11] = 115 or s
i = 11
-X-X-X-X-X-X
s1[11] = 115 or s
s2[11] = 98 or b
-X-X-X-X-X-X

i = 12
-X-X-X-X-X-X
s1[12] = 105 or i
s2[12] = 0 or
i = 12
-X-X-X-X-X-X
s1[12] = 0 or
s2[12] = 105 or i
-X-X-X-X-X-X

i = 13
-X-X-X-X-X-X
s1[13] = 114 or r
s2[13] = 66 or B
i = 13
-X-X-X-X-X-X
s1[13] = 66 or B
s2[13] = 114 or r
-X-X-X-X-X-X

i = 14
-X-X-X-X-X-X
s1[14] = 100 or d
s2[14] = 97 or a
i = 14
-X-X-X-X-X-X
s1[14] = 97 or a
s2[14] = 100 or d
-X-X-X-X-X-X

i = 15
-X-X-X-X-X-X
s1[15] = 0 or
s2[15] = 110 or n
i = 15
-X-X-X-X-X-X
s1[15] = 110 or n
s2[15] = 0 or
-X-X-X-X-X-X

s1 is now: rd
s2 is now: Banned Playbird

I added debugging print statements to examine what's going on . Everything seems to be fine and both should get printed till '\0' character is reached in their swapped strings but for some reason s1 gets omitted and takes up last 2 characters of s2 . At i = 12 , 'i' of s1 gets swapped with null character of s2 and at i = 15 , null character of s1 gets swapped with some undefined value in s2[15].
The interesting thing is that this starts happening only after 'i' goes beyond the common length of s1 and s2 . I want to know about possible inaccuracies I might have committed in my code .

You access the smaller array out of bounds.

You can't swap these two strings. Since you didn't specify the array size when you declared s1 and s2, they each only have enough room for the strings they're initialized with. Since s2 is shorter than s1, you can't copy all of s1 into it.

And the loop stops before the null terminator of the longer string.

It can be more efficient to swap pointers to strings, buffers, etc, than moving the actual data around.

@WeatherVane Yes, but OP is playing with arrays, so that doesn’t really help him.

@Dúthomhas the strings and buffers I mentioned are arrays. The OP's data does not have the spare bytes that you advocate in your answer, to enable a data swap. In which case, swapping pointers is the way to go. And even if the objects are the same size, it may still be the way to go.

@WeatherVane But the bulk of OP’s code attempts to swap the content. Which error do you think OP is more likely to have committed? An intentional effort to play with the content? Or a declaration lacking size? Occam’s Razor applies.

@Dúthomhas we don't know the source of OP's MRE. They may have hard-coded the strings for the presentation. Suppose you are sorting 10000 strings of varying length? What do you think is the way to go? Force them all to the same length, repeated copying used and unused bytes, or set up an array of pointers? And suppose one of those strings has a milion characters, while most have less than 42?

never call a function repeatedly unnecessarily like strlen(s1)>strlen(s2)?strlen(s1):strlen(s2). Just store the length and reuse. Similarly never do something like for (i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++)...

@WeatherVane Yes I am aware of the swapping pointers method ,  I intentionally tried this out to exploit a phenomenon in C where even if you have an array of length 5 , you can access and edit the 40th position and the compiler has no problems with it . I know that's a bad practice but it works out not in my favour this time . Do you think that there is no actual rationality behind accessing out of bounds locations and once I do that , I am in uncharted territory and anything can happen beyond the realms of logic ?

As already noted in the comments, both arrays need to be large enough to hold the content of the largest string. You can just make them both fairly big, easily enough:
int main(void)
{
    char s1[100] = "Small string";
    char s2[100] = "A somewhat larger string";

⟶ Remember that a string in C is just a bunch of characters terminating at the first character with a value of zero (or nul). The array may be bigger than the string, and anything following that nul character is random noise, but it is still part of the array.
If you declare an array without supplying a size, you get an array exactly as large as necessary to hold the string, nothing more.
Now you can apply a swap algorithm.
Thoughts on the algorithm:

You need to stop swapping values when you hit a nul-terminator (\0), but there are two of them (one for each string): which one should you stop at?

What if the strings are the same length? How can you tell if they are?


You can do all this with a single for or while loop.
void swap( char * a, char * b )
{
    //loop goes here
}

Get rid of all the printf()s and stuff inside the swap() function. At this point they are just getting in your way.
Remember, it helps to get out a piece of paper and draw what you expect to happen, at least once.

Yes , its this aspect of the problem that I was unsure of.The fact that they are of unequal sizes , but I have also seen in an array of length 5 , I can make edits to the 40th position and access that just fine . I know this feels illegal to do and in professional field we should strive to avoid this type of code , but I wonder why it did not work out this time . Everything upto the '\0' index of the longer string does get swapped including the '\0' of the shorter string and puts() should make a halt when it encounters that '\0' in each of the strings , right ?

@MikeBillings The way memory is laid out for your program may make it possible for you to access and edit past the end of your array, but what that memory actually is is unknown to you, and you could be doing a great deal of damage to your program. This is why it is undefined behavior to access data beyond the defined array. Remember, the string may end before the space allotted to it. That is, the string may be shorter than the array that holds it. This is why my code creates two arrays of 100 characters — both arrays are (more than) sufficient to hold the two strings to be swapped.

... an array of length 5 , I can make edits to the 40th position and access that just fine: Well, it's as fine as running a red traffic light, you will get away with it until the day you won't.


char s1[] = "Banned Playbird" ;
char s2[] = "Banned Birds" ;

char var_name[] = "xxxxx";
Use this way to define a variable in memory then the allocated memory size is the str(var_name) + 1(include a '\0')
So memory size of s1 is not equal to s2, it is why you can't move the bytes from s1 to s2, it will cause your s2 over the bounds.
The way to let you swap two bytes in different area is setting them in a same size room like this.
char s1[20] = "Banned Playbird" ;
char s2[20] = "Banned Birds" ;
If memory over the bounds then you may change the other byte in RAM, It may cause a serious fault in you program. So careful you memory size. it is very important in C program.
The power of C is very strong, you can use the C code in your hand to change any local memory area. So restrict the power.
I am not a english native speaker, if you think my answer have any error in english please feel free to edit it.
